# php decode JSON get values

Tags: php, json, postman

I'm trying to decode JSON format

What I am sending is:

```
{
"id": 123,
"name": "John",
“surname”: “Smith”,
“department”: 3
}
```

I am sending POST with data via Postman, in the picture.
So, this is the data I want to decode:

```
"data_serever_received": "{ \"id\": 123, \"name\": \"john\", “surname”: “Smith”, “department”: 3 }"
```

[image]

I tried

```
$this->input->data["id"]
```

but it is not working.

How can I get the id, name, surname and etc. values?

Comment: the output named user on the picture is $this->input->data

Comment: Except using the correct quotes instead, right?

Comment: I suggest you also use `Content-Type: application/json` to make the process better.

Comment: Those aren't the right quotes (`"`)

Comment: why you are sending “surname” , “Smith” and “department” in ” instead of " ?

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is invalid `“` and `”` are not `"`.

(Zoom in with your browser if you can't see the difference).

You need to start with valid JSON before you can parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode to make it an array.

```
$json_array = json_decode($json_object);//$json_object will need to contain your json string.
```

then you can access like this:

```
echo $json_array["data"][“surname”];
```

PHP Doc on json_decode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i do that i get null in $json_array

Comment: what is the $_POST variable that the json string is in?

Comment: $_POST looks like this: "POST": {
        "user": "{ \"id\": 123, \"name\": \"john\", “surname”: “Smith”, “department”: 3 }"
    }

Comment: Ok, and you are doing `json_decode($_POST['your_json_string'])`?

Comment: Will you add your complete code to the question please.